# Files copied using xcopy command are hidden in destination

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

I copied almost 100GB of files from my laptop to my external drive using the following `xcopy` command.

```
X:\windows\system32>XCOPY E:\ "L:\BackupFolder\" /S /E
```

All the files in `E:` were copied to `BackupFolder` but now I cannot see the backup folder in my external drive. But I can see the space taken by that copy. I don't know where the copied files have gone.

[image]
[image]
[image]

They must be there in the external drive, but I can neither see nor access them. I even tried showing hidden files and folders but it didn't help me.

I can however see the copied folders and files when I do `dir /a` from the command prompt.

Has anybody experienced this problem? How can I find and access the copied backup files?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have permissions to access the folders on the target drive.  Log in as admin and then see if they are visible.

Comment: I am logged as admin.. but cannot see anything on the drive..

Comment: Can you see the files on the command line (`dir /a`).

Comment: Yes i can see all the folders and files if i run dir /a command

Answer (score 6):

When specifying an entire drive as source, also add source wildcard. Example:

```
xcopy "S:\*.*" "D:\destdirectory" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
```

then the H and S attributes are not set in the destination.

Comment: This worked for me, but would be nice to have more explanation. As others noted specifying . or S:\ somehow made the dest dir have a system attribute even when not including hidden files in the copy. ...I did have symlinks in the source.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue when using xcopy.

The folder has been set as system file and has become hidden from Windows Explorer

To unhide the folder, run this command:

`attrib -s -h D:\hiddenfoldername`

Reference:
https://www.faqforge.com/windows/hide-folders-by-making-them-system-folders-on-windows/

Answer (score 4):

Your files are being copied but the destination files have been set as protected system files. Showing hidden files will not show you protected system files, this is a separate option under view, alternately you can type the directory path into the address bar and you will be able to  see your files.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue when using Robocopy.  I don't know why, but the target folder gets marked as both hidden **and** a system folder.  You can see if if you go to the parent folder and run

> dir /ahs

To un-hide it, run

> attrib /d /s -s -h *foldername*

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar/related issue.  User files on old pc are visible and usable.  Attempting to copy all my documents files to a USB drive and copy then to a new windows 10 pc (from Win7), the files are not visible.  I even pulled the hard drive out of the win 7 pc and tethered it to a usb interface, plugged it into the win10 machine, and under the users folder the User/subfolder Bill (his win7 username) was not visible.

Pulled his Macrium Reflect backup from USB drive, hosted it on new machine, browsed the backup file, same thing.  I can only see Public, not the user itself.  Short of emailing about 5Gb from old pc to new, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This does not answer the author’s question.